# Creating dataframe rows with timestamp increments

Tags: r, dataframe, date, datetime

I have a dataframe with a structure similar to this:

| name | time_from | time_to | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-01-01 01:30:00 | value1 |
| a | 2020-01-01 02:00:00 | 2020-01-01 02:30:00 | value2 |
| b | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-01-01 01:00:00 | value3 |

I want to convert the dataframe to the following structure by increasing the `time_from` timestamp by 30 minutes up to the `time_to` timestamp value while the `name` and `value` remain the same over the timestamp increments.

| name | time | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | value1 |
| a | 2020-01-01 00:30:00 | value1 |
| a | 2020-01-01 01:00:00 | value1 |
| a | 2020-01-01 01:30:00 | value1 |
| a | 2020-01-01 02:00:00 | value2 |
| a | 2020-01-01 02:30:00 | value2 |
| b | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | value3 |
| b | 2020-01-01 00:30:00 | value3 |
| b | 2020-01-01 01:00:00 | value3 |

Help and guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a clear and well-written question, thanks! It seems to me there are a few steps: breaking the interval from `time_from` to `time_to` into 30-minute chunks, and then splitting the data appropriately across the timestamps. I'd look to the package `lubridate` to help with the interval splitting part, and then, to stay in the `tidyverse`, potentially use `pivot_longer` to  make 1 row per time stamp... fun problem!

Comment: Thank you very much! It is a fun problem to solve indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `seqPOSIXt` in a `by` approach.

```
dat <- do.call(rbind, by(dat, dat[c('name', 'value')], function(x) {
  setNames(
    data.frame(x[1, 1], seq.POSIXt(x[1, 2], x[nrow(x), 3], by='30 min'), x[1, 4]),
    c('name', 'time', 'value'))}))
dat
#   name                time  value
# 1    a 2020-01-01 00:00:00 value1
# 2    a 2020-01-01 00:30:00 value1
# 3    a 2020-01-01 01:00:00 value1
# 4    a 2020-01-01 01:30:00 value1
# 5    a 2020-01-01 02:00:00 value2
# 6    a 2020-01-01 02:30:00 value2
# 7    b 2020-01-01 00:00:00 value3
# 8    b 2020-01-01 00:30:00 value3
# 9    b 2020-01-01 01:00:00 value3
```

Of course, the solution assumes correctly formated 'POSIXct' format as input. Convert beforehand if you don't have it:

```
tcols <- c('time_from', 'time_to')
dat[tcols] <- lapply(dat[tcols], as.POSIXct)
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(name = c("a", "a", "b"), time_from = structure(c(1577833200, 
1577840400, 1577833200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    time_to = structure(c(1577838600, 1577842200, 1577836800), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), value = c("value1", "value2", "value3"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: thank you very much for the solution. Apologies as I forgot to add that my dataframe has multiple rows with the same `name` while having different `time_from` , `time_to` and `value`. I have edited the tables in the main post that reflects this. 

Currently running into an error stating: 
"Error in seq.POSIXt(x[[2]], x[[3]], by = "30 min") : 'from' must be of length 1"

Comment: @user15962592 Just add value to the indices in `by`, see update.